# dynamic JsonProperty deserialise for data driven tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automation, nunit

I am trying to automate some tests and I am looking for a way to add a dynamic JsonProperty

So for example i could have a Json response like this

```
"data": {
        "ADA": {
            "id": 2010,
        },
        "BTC": {
            "id": 1,
        },
        "ETH": {
            "id": 1027,
        },
```

```
public class QuotesLatest
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CryptoCurrency
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of doing something like this and having to list out each potential value, i want to be able to access each cryptocurrency dynamically

```
 public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("BTC")]
        public CryptoCurrency BTC { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ETH")]
        public CryptoCurrency ETH { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ADA")]
        public CryptoCurrency ADA { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DOGE")]
        public CryptoCurrency DOGE { get; set; }
    }
```

I was looking to do something like this but i am unsure how to make the JsonProperty Dynamic?

```
    public class Data
    {
        public List<CryptoCurrency> CryptoCurrency {get; set;}
    }
```

I want to be able to assert each dynamically similar to below using data driven tests

```
Assert.That(quotesLatest.Data.CryptoCurrency[{cryptocurreny}].Id, Is.EqualTo(id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class QuotesLatest
{
    // I am assuming this is the class where you have the 'Data' property.

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, CryptoCurrency> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Where CryptoCurrency:

```
public class CryptoCurrency
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

`quotesLatest.Data["BTC"].Id` returns `1` for me.